# Is there an alternative to using a serializer for drf-spectacular's extend_schema request param?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, drf-spectacular

I'm using [drf-spectacular](https://drf-spectacular.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) to generate swagger/redoc API documentation.

One of the most useful features is the ability to test requests via the generated swagger html page, but I'd like to enforce the *application/x-www-form-urlencoded* content-type so that when the request is received by my Django endpoints, *the request.data* has the encoded data instead of it ending up as part of a query string. drf-spectacular always seems to default to query strings e.g. */objects/action/?key=value*

The only way I've figured out how to do this is to [use a serializer in conjunction with the request content-type](https://drf-spectacular.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customization.html) e.g.

```
@extend_schema(
    request={'application/x-www-form-urlencoded': DoTheActionInputsSerializer},
    responses={200: DoTheActionOutputsSerializer},
    methods=["POST"]
)
@action(methods=['post'], detail=False)
def do_the_action(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    ...
```

This works great, but it does require a lot of small serializers that may only have one or two attributes. Is there an alternative way of achieving this inside the extend_schema decorator?

I was hoping something like the following would work, but doesn't

```
request={'application/x-www-form-urlencoded': {'schema': {'foo_id': OpenApiTypes.INT}}},
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the [documentation](https://drf-spectacular.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customization.html?highlight=inline_serializer#step-2-extend-schema) answers that question. You can use `inline_serializer` for those small one-off cases. It allows you to do this:

```py
    @extend_schema(responses={
        '2XX': SimpleSerializer,
        '401': inline_serializer('Error1', fields={'detail': serializers.CharField()}),
    })
```

This works the same for `@extend_schema(request=inline_serializer(...))`

As a matter of last resort, you can also put a raw schema dict into `request`  or `response`.

**Note:** If you want `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` to be detected automatically, just do

```py
@action(methods=['post'], detail=False, parser_classes=[parsers.FormParser])
```

Comment: Thanks. I can't believe I totally missed that. In case it helps for anyone, the raw schema to try and achieve a simple serializer ended up looking like the following, so not very helpful.

request={'application/json': {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "id": {
            "type": "integer",
            "format": "int64"
        },
    },
    "required": [
        "id",
    ],
    "example": {
        "id": 123456789012345678
    }
}
},